# Artifactory Polling timeout in github action CICD

Tags: deployment, github-actions, artifactory, cicd

I have a CICD process to build docker and deploy it. I am using Jfrog to save the docker image and use it for deployment.

For each project, I just save a couple of latest images so I don't think the issue is due to having low storage issue.

I am able to build the image without issue but when I want to deploy, with "docker run" command, I receive this error:

> 2022-12-19T20:15:34.0073431Z 2022-12-19 20:15:34 INFO     Current task: Docker push -app
> Blockquote
>
> 2022-12-19T20:20:15.0249846Z cloud.exceptions.PlayTimeout: Polling
> timeout has been reached for d8bdabd4-7fd9-11ed-b4e3-005056bc8da6.
> Status remains running.
>
> 2022-12-19T20:20:15.0711629Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code
> 1.

The docker run command is something like this:

```
docker run -e USER={{ DB_USER }} -e PASSWORD={{ DB_PASSWORD}} -e ENV={{RUNNING_HOSTNAME}} -d -p 8140:8140 --restart unless-stopped --name AAA artifacts******/analytics-docker/dataservices/AAA/dev:AAA-{{ RUN_NUMBER }}
```

duration of the failed process:

Total duration

35m 48s

Build process duration

29m 58s

Deploy process duration

5m 34s

let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Do you see any requests reaching Artifactory at this time? Any errors in the Artifactory logs?

Comment: I don't have access to artifactory logs but it's probable that is the case. Is it possible to upgrade Jfrog to a higher tier on an enterprise account?

Comment: TBH, without the Artifactory logs I cannot comment on the subscription issue.